# Represent a problem with only one graph

Tags: trigonometry

A man who is at the south of a lighthouse observes that his shadow cast by the lighthouse has a length of 4m; if he walks 60m to the west, he observes that his shadow has a length of 5m. If the person is 1m tall, find the height of the lighthouse.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Can you show us what you tried so that we can guide you better?

Comment: Keep in mind that questions that appear to consider Math.SE a homework-answering service are prone to be downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that in the first position (South) the man is distant $x_1$ from the base of the lighthouse. In the second position (South-West) the man is distant $x_2 = \sqrt{60^2+x_1^2}$ from the base.

Consider now two triangles:

- TL: top of the lighthouse, base of the lighthouse, end of the shadow.
- TM: top of the man, base of the man, end of the shadow.

TL and TM are similar (they have different sides but same angles), so you can write some proportionality relations:
$$
\text{height of TL} : \text{height of TM} = \text{base of TL} : \text{base of TM}
$$
For the two positions (South and South-West) you have:
$$
h : 1 = (x_1+4) : 4
$$
and 
$$
h : 1 = (x_2+5) : 5 
$$
where $h$ is the height of the lighthouse and $1$ is the height of the man. 
Remember that $x_2$ can be written in terms of $x_1$: now you have a system of two equations for the two unknowns  $x_1$ and $h$ (you want $h$ but to find it you have to find also $x_1$).

At this point is is possible to solve the problem exactly but the calculations are simpler if you make a legit approximation: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are much larger than $4$ or $5$ (because $h\gg 1$), so the above equations read
$$
h : 1 \approx  x_1  : 4
$$
and 
$$
h : 1 \approx  x_2  : 5 
$$
Take the square of everything to find 
 $$
h^2  \approx  x_1^2  / 4^2
$$
and 
$$
h^2 \approx  x_2^2  /5^2 = (60^2 + x_1^2 ) /25
$$
You can solve  $x_1^2  / 16 = (60^2 + x_1^2 ) /25$ and find $x_1$, then insert the value of $x_1$ into $h^2  \approx  x_1^2  / 4^2$ to find $h$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The base and the top of the lighthouse
are labeled with the points $O$ and $A$, respectively,

Let $D$ be the point of the first measurement and
$|OD|=a$ is the distance from it to the base of the lighthouse,
$F$ is the point of the second measurement and
$|OF|=b$ is the distance from it to the base of the lighthouse,
$|DF|=w=60$ is the distance between the two points of measurement,
$|ED|=|GF|=1$ is the height of the stick,
$|DB|=4$ and $|FC|=5$ are the measurements of the shadow length.
Note that $\angle AOB=\angle AOC=\angle FDO=90^\circ$,
and we have
\begin{align} 
\triangle AOB,\,\triangle EDB:\quad
\frac{c}{a+u}&=\frac1u
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\triangle AOC,\,\triangle GFC:\quad
\frac{c}{b+v}&=\frac1v
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\frac{a+u}u &= \frac{b+v}v
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
b&=\frac{av}u
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
b^2&=\frac{a^2v^2}{u^2}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\triangle OFD:\quad
b^2-a^2&=w^2
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
\frac{a^2v^2}{u^2}-a^2
&=w^2
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
a&=\frac{uw}{\sqrt{v^2-u^2}}
=\frac{4\cdot60}{\sqrt{5^2-4^2}}
=80
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
c&=\frac{a+u}u
=\frac{80+4}4=21
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}